# sass - invalid css for chrome

Tags: css, sass

I'm using sass. I created a function that calculates pixels into rem. But there is always a whitespace behind the numeric value and thus Chrome cannto read that property. How can I change the function?

SASS

```
@function rem($pixels) {
  @return ($pixels/16)rem;
}


.header{
width: rem(120);
}
```

wrong CSS

```
.header{
width: 7.5 rem;
}
```

corrrect CSS

```
   .header{
width: 7.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try interpolation for this:

```
@function rem($pixels) {
  @return #{($pixels/16)}rem;
}
```